# Query Append used with a dropdown. it works, but It stops append after selected once

Tags: html, jquery, append, dropdown

The dropdown should add as many appends as it is clicked. Currently, I can click  "London" and get an instance and it stops, but I can click the second "Paris" selection and it adds an instance of "Paris" and then go back and add another instance of "London" in an alternating fashion. Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adventurly/ub4o680h/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        if ((selectedOption) == "London") {
            $("#container").append("This is London ");

        } 
        if ((selectedOption) == "Paris") {

            $("#container").append("This is Paris ");
        }

        
    });
});
```

```
    <form>
        <label>City:</label>
        <select>
            <option>London</option>
            <option>Paris</option>

        </select>
    </form>
    <p></p>
     
    <div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah because you are calling onchange event. When you click on already selected option again, it changes nothing. Because od that the function does not get called.

Instead you should try calling onClick event to achieve this.

Comment: When I use the click event it doesn't stop to determine what is being selected it just adds a bunch of random appends.

Comment: Can you pls update the fiddle with the same ?

Comment: yes, I updated the fiddle with the onClick event.

Comment: I still see the onchange even in the fiddle. However i feel it won't be possible using default dropdown. As there is no event to listen the click of already selected option.  However if you still wanna achieve the same, try using custom selectbox such as bootstrap select and add jquery to it. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look.